# Visual editor not working in wordpress 3.8.1?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have just updated wordpress to 3.8.1 and visual editor not working in page and post.
I have tried with following solutions but none of them works for me.

-Activate and deactivate all plugin.

-installed Use Google Libraries plugin.

-Changed theme.

-unchecked in user profile for "Disable the visual editor when writing".

-cleared browser cache.

-Reinstalled wordpress.

-added this line to wp-config.php
define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );

Comment: Looks like this is a WordPress Core issue. See [this link](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/visual-editor-not-working-in-381)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for replay.
I have solved this issue by manually download wordpress 3.8.1 and uploaded wp-admin and wp-includes folders using ftp. 
Now its working nicely.

Answer (score 0):

disable and re-enable the Yoast SEO plugin,