# Wordpress update cause visual editor blank

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I updated my wordpress website version with 3.9.2. After updating when i try to add or update any page or post, visual editor tab shows blank. It does not display toolbar buttons or page or post content. Text tab works fine

I tried following solutions provided on different sites with no luck

1) clear browser cache

2) deactivating all plugins

3) change to default theme and again change to desired one

The people who had the same issue had cured the problem by doing one of these suggestions:

1) Install “Use Google Libraries” plugin

2) Add to your wp-config.php file:

```
define( ‘CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS’, false );
```

3) Download a refresh version of WordPress from WordPress.org and via ftp replace /wp-includes/js/tinymce folder

4) Download a refresh version of WordPress from WordPress.org and via ftp replace /wp-includes folder

I tried all above solutions but no success :(

I also refer following links but could not find solution

[Wordpress Visual Editor broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217022/wordpress-visual-editor-broken)

[Visual editor not working in wordpress 3.8.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21430265/visual-editor-not-working-in-wordpress-3-8-1)

I have attached screen-shoot for visual editor tab and text editor tab for one page

Please help

[image]
[image]

Comment: What theme you are using? Can you switch into default theme for testing purpose. It might be due to theme.

Comment: I have seen a problem like this where the .css was messing things up and showing white text on a white background, check if you can select/highlight anything in the visual editor

Comment: I tried to select / highlight but nothing shows. @Loopo

Comment: I tried to switch to default theme and then again to my theme but no luck @AnandMishra

Comment: Are you getting any JavaScript errors?

Comment: I am getting one error but i don't know why it is coming or is it related to my problem or not. Failed to load: undefined/ - [MY_SITE_URL]/wp-admin/undefined/

Comment: Do you have enable_more_buttons() function in function.php ? if yes disable the code //  $buttons[] = 'styleselect';

Comment: @Vidhi did you found a solution for this issue? I am facing same thing, and I did same procedure as you, still unsuccessful.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue on APlus.net Hosting and had one heck of a time fixing it. All the text in the Visual Editor was white, and I couldn't get to the HTML tab. The Visual Editor was missing all the formatting buttons -- it was just a white empty space.

After trying everything listed across the web without success, I was finally able to track down the culprit on APlus hosting. It turns out APlus hosting injects their own analytics tracking code into even the WordPress Admin pages. The code for their analytics wasn't written properly -- the code was missing a final ending apostrophe, which resulted in breaking all the code that came after it. In my scenario, the injected code broke the Page Editor TinyMCE JS code.

I checked the Google Chrome inspector to find the error in the code, and after talking with a Tech Support rep at APlus I was able to fix it by deleting the analytics file on the server via FTP:

```
/private/.wmcnum
```

I hope this helps. If anything check out the Google Chrome inspector and look for errors. If it's something you can't change, definitely get in touch with your hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen an issue like this before. For me, the site we were updating had many out of date plugins. The one that caused our issue was WP Polls. Something went wrong during the update process, and certain files were missing from the plugin directory. I kept a backup of all of the files from before the update, but even re-uploading them didn't fix it. We ended up removing the plugin that was causing the issues and re-installing it. If you can narrow down which plugin might have some discrepancies, then I'd recommend backing everything up (including your database), deleting the plugin, and re-installing it.

If it was simply a WordPress update, it may be that not all of the WordPress files copied over. If you can get a fresh install of WordPress 3.9.2, you can compare the differences between those files and the files on your site. If you're getting an error from somewhere in wp-admin, I'd start my check there.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that worked for me:

“Use PHPMyAdmin (or another database editor) to search inside your WordPress database in your “wp_options” table for the record called “can_compress_scripts”. and if it has a value of “1” for the “option_value”, change this to “0” and save the change. You will find your editor working again! (Note: Sometimes this record won’t even exist, so in that case you need to add it. Look for a WordPress database that does have it in order to see what you need to add.)"

original answer by digbymaass:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/visual-editor-missing-buttons-not-working-white-text-help-1/

Answer (score 0):

In my experience I've had some problems with the tinymce editor. Some of my clients reported they've 'lost' some of the buttons in the editor (or all of them).

I found that disabling emojis with the tiny_mce_plugins filter not also disables emojis but half the buttons in the editor.

Maybe you have somewhere in functions.php this line, just comment it and refresh cache. Let's see if that helps.

```
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_plugins', 'disable_emojicons_tinymce' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked all over about this. I could not edit or see text in wordpress posts or pages. It seemed to narrow down to the tinymce plugin where I found errors through the Chrome console. I tried a number of things without luck. So I disabled tinymce and all is running smoothly. How simple for a problem with so many variables and options for a fix.